# How to register a .Net Standard OPC UA Reference Server to an Local Discovery Server?

Tags: c#, .net, opc-ua

My problem is that I cannot get an OPC UA .NET Standard [Console Reference Server](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/tree/master/Applications/ConsoleReferenceServer) to connect to my Local Discovery Server. The server is supposed to run on a Raspberry Pi, so I can't use the "normal" [Reference Server](https://github.com/OPCFoundation/UA-.NETStandard/tree/master/Applications/ReferenceServer). At least I haven't found a way to build it for Linux yet.

The "normal" Reference Server provides a method to connect me to an LDS whose data I have stored in the .config.xml. This all works as well.
However, the console server uses a different server class, so I can't use the same methods that I could use with the "normal" reference server.
On the Github page it also says that the servers are set to automatically connect to an LDS running on the localhost, I have not observed this behavior either.

"normal" Reference Server:

```
// Create server, add additional node managers
var server = new ReferenceServer();
Quickstarts.Servers.Utils.AddDefaultNodeManagers(server);

// start the server.
application.Start(server).Wait();
server.RegisterWithDiscoveryServer();
```

Console Reference Server

```
// create the UA server
var server = new UAServer<ReferenceServer>(output) {
    AutoAccept = autoAccept,
    Password = password
};
```

Ideas and suggestions on how to connect the ConsolenReferenceServer to my Local discovery Server are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out what the problem was: 
In the config file there is a tag with the name `<MaxRegistrationDuration>`, there must be a value entered that is greater than zero. Then everything works as expected